# how to listen for vcard changes of any of my roster entries

Tags: xmpp, smack, openfire, asmack

is there is any way in smack library that make me able to be updated with changes in vcard of any of my contacts
I tried roster listener and packets listeners which listen for Iq packets but I couldn't get any thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: With the currently [deployed vCard spec](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html), you can't get notifications of changes.  You can however, [detect when the embedded avatar changes](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0153.html).

In the [new, vCard4-based spec](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0292.html), this is solved by re-using [PEP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html) for notifications. Unfortunately, it isn't widely deployed yet.

Comment: this was a great help it opens my mind on the vcard spes I was unaware of

Comment: using the references by @Zash I got these links which intreduce how to use PEP in SMACK http://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/peppersonal-eventing-protocol-with-smack/